# Determine counterclockwise moving

Tags: circles

in my app, I let user touch and move to draw an arc. After drawing, I got a set of points. Is there any way to determine that user draw the arc counterclockwise or reverse counter clock wise?

Comment: "*reverse counter clock wise*" - i.e., clockwise :) By the way, a fun word for counterclockwise is "widdershins" (the counterpart for clockwise is "deosil"). [See this English.SE thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60703/9722).

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed a circle you need only find an expression in a form that defines an angle $\theta$ between the initial point and later points.

Once you've got that angle check if $\tan \frac{1}{4}\theta$ is increasing. If it is, it is moving counter clockwise.

Note this only works for angles between $0$ and $2 \pi$

Comment: +1, What do you mean about `check if tan14θ is increasing`? Could you please give me more details or example?

Answer (score 0):

The set of points will obviously be stored in an order. Circular array/list or even a plain array. Just compare the coordinates of consecutive points.